# Make a 16 bit integer from 3 bytes with 31 max value (5 bits)

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I want to make a 16 bit value from 3 little endian bytes with a max value of 31 (this means they're maximum of 5 set bits). How would I get the last 5 bits of the bytes, then put them all together?

e.g. bytes : 0011111 0010101 0011100 into 1111110101111000

I tried this but I think I'm just overwriting my old bits

```
cp = (bar << 3) | (bag >> 2) | (bab >> 7);
```

Comment: Heh, I like the downvotes guys.. Thanks for downvoting a legitimate question for someone who wants to expand their knowledge on how bit-shifting works :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not overwriting bits, but you are shifting bits out of the values before even putting them together. `bag >> 2` leaves only three bits of the original and `bab >> 7` shifts out all five bits plus two more.

Shift the values to the left instead:

```
cp = (bar << 10) | (bag << 5) | bab;
```

You want to make room on the right for the other values:

```
bar << 10  -11111----------
bag << 5   ------10101-----
bab        -----------11100
```

Comment: That code results in this for me : http://puu.sh/jVndm.png where bar and bag = 31 (11111) :/

Comment: No wonder I'm so confused. The hex editor I'm using to view binary is displaying it differently, but it still has the same value of 32444. So this code does in fact work. Thanks so much! :)

Comment: @aaro4130: The value is stored in little endian format, so the two bytes `00000000 01111100` is the 16 bit value `0111110000000000`.